# KentorAuthServices - Service Provider certificate error with SHA2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, sha256, kentor-authservices

Configuring Service Provider certificate in our .NEt Mvc web application using the store.

When configured  use="Both" -> It is saying not a valid cert for encrypt/Decrypt
When Configured use="Signing" -> It is saying 
Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqa79.jpg)

Comment: does the application pool have permission to the private key of both certificates?

Comment: I am testing in my local box, So its running on iis express. Did not try deploying it to any server yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the certificate issue. They were two reasons.

1)  X509Certificate2 doesn’t support certificates associated with a CNG private key provider. I have to regenerate certificate using RSA key provider.
2)  Once the certificate is installed to store, Give the full access to “Network Service” as the IIS application runs in this context. For locally, I gave access to "Everyone"

Hope this helps someone looking at this issue!